# System.outofmemory exception when running Powershell script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, visual-c++, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

I've written VC++ code to run Powershell scripts on a remote server. I create a PSSession to a server first and then I run around 30000 commandlets. While performing this operation, I receive System.outofmemory exception. I've also tried to increase 'MaxMemoryPerShellMB' to 2048, but that doesn't solve the problem. Kindly advise. This is my code:

```
runSpace = RunspaceFactory::CreateRunspace();
    runSpace->Open();
    ps = PowerShell::Create();
    ps->Runspace = runSpace;        
    PSCommand^ rmcommand = gcnew PSCommand();
    Uri^ uri = gcnew Uri("http://"+ serverName +"/powershell?serializationLevel=Full");
    rmcommand->AddCommand("New-PSSession");
    rmcommand->AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
    rmcommand->AddParameter("ConnectionUri", uri);
    rmcommand->AddParameter("Authentication", "kerberos");
    rmcommand->AddParameter("Name", "pssession");
    PSSessionOption^ sessionOption = gcnew PSSessionOption();
    sessionOption->SkipCACheck = true;
    sessionOption->SkipCNCheck = true;
    sessionOption->SkipRevocationCheck = true;
    rmcommand->AddParameter("SessionOption", sessionOption);
    ps->Commands = rmcommand;
    Collection<PSObject^>^ result = ps->Invoke();
        rmcommand = gcnew PSCommand();
        rmcommand->AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
        ps->Commands = rmcommand;
        ps->Invoke();

        rmcommand = gcnew PSCommand();
        rmcommand->AddScript("Import-PSSession -Session $session -CommandName 'Get-MailboxStatistics'");
        ps->Commands = rmcommand;
        ps->Invoke();

PSCommand^ command = gcnew PSCommand();

        for(size i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
        {

            mbxidentity=mailbox[i];

            command = gcnew PSCommand();
            command->AddScript("Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity \'" + mbxidentity + "\' | select LegacyDN");
            ps->Commands = command;
            Collection<PSObject^>^ result = ps->Invoke(); 
//Do something with result
        }
```

Here 'mailbox' is an array containing list of mailbox identities. Also, I get Outofmemory at different places. Sometimes I get it when running New-PSSession itself. Sometimes, around 1000 commandlets run successfully and then I get the exception. What might be the problem? I have checked the memory of the remote serve and it is fine.

Comment: Are you sure the out of memory exception is happening in this code and not the "do something with the result" part? If you add something that simply writes out the `LegacyDN`-value to the console in the loop, do you still get out of memory exception? When you recieved the error in the `New-PSSession` Call, was that With a New process or is this the action of a button that you had pushed multiple times before (so the process itself had been building up alot of memory usage during the previous clicks)?

Comment: I'm sure the exception is happening in this code. Actually, there are around 4 threads like this that concurrently opens 4 sessions to different servers and executes the script. So I'm not sure if it is a new process or not. One question: when I create a new session and run scripts, which memory is used to run these scripts? I've tried setting MaxMemoryPerShellMB in both the client machine and the server but to no avail. Where can I check how much memory is used by the Powershell script?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I don't have much experience with running PowerShell using c++ or c#. If you have one process which creates all 4 runspaces / sessions, then the is in the process, isn't it (threads share memory)? Have you tried running the code as a normal powershell script to see if you can recreate the issue there?

Comment: Yes, I did try running the code as a script and it worked fine. But on running this project, I'm getting the same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with running powershell code with c++/c#. My comments were getting big, so I'll use an answer to ask questions etc.

- Have you restarted the winrm-service on the server(s) after raising
  the MaxMemoryPerShellMB?
- Why are you running `Get-Mailbox`? I can't see that you're storing the output anywhere, and this would probably create a lot of objects = memory-usage

Comment: No, I've not restarted the winrm-service. Is it necessary? I'm not running get-mailbox but get-mailboxstatistics. My mistake, I've updated the code.

Comment: Restart the server or at least the winrm-service for the new memorysetting to apply. http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx

Comment: One more question, if I connect to remote Powershell from a client machine to an Exchange server, should I increase the MaxMemoryPerShellMB in the client machine or the server?

Comment: I haven't found any documentation about it yet, but the winrm service is used for remoting, so I'm 90% sure that you only need to raise it on the server to allow a Remote Connection to use more memory on the server (which is where the Remote session is using Resources).